# Theorem Style Design

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm trying to design a a theorem style using the code below. However, I would like to be able to write the name of the Theorem right after the phrase. I mean I'd like to have

---

### Theorem 1 (First Theorem)

### bla bla bla

on the bar on top of the frame. Do you have any ideas how to do it? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\mdtheorem[roundcorner=5pt,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
 shadow=true,frametitlerule=true,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={left color=gray!10!white,right color=white},
mdfframetitlebackground/.append style ={left color=white,right color=gray!10!white}}}]{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}    

\begin{Theorem}
If $a^m=a^n$ then $m=n$ or $a=1$ or $a=-1$ and $m$, $n$ are even integers.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to get rid of the double colon? If not, my answer shows how it could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\mdtheorem[roundcorner=5pt,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
 shadow=true,frametitlerule=true,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={left color=gray!10!white,right color=white},
mdfframetitlebackground/.append style ={left color=white,right color=gray!10!white}}}]{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}    

\begin{Theorem}[(First Theorem)]
If $a^m=a^n$ then $m=n$ or $a=1$ or $a=-1$ and $m$, $n$ are even integers.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]